# Backbone.stickit works on forms but not contenteditable

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.stickit for two way binding between a View and a Model. I would like to use a contenteditable span as the bound DOM element, but that's not working.

If I use this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="textbox-template">
    <!--<span id="content" contenteditable/>-->
    <input type='text' id='content'/>
</script>
```

two way binding works as anticipated. If I use the span rather than the input element, changes do not push back to the model. Note that onGet works, so the original model attribute value is visible. However, I've confirmed that onSet is not called, so an event isn't firing properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Backbone.stickit looks for](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit/blob/master/backbone.stickit.js#L304) the `contenteditable` attribute where its value is `true` so to make it work you need to write:

```
<script type="text/template" id="textbox-template">
    <span id="content" contenteditable="true"/>
    <input type='text' id='content'/>
</script>
```